# Swap 99% but regular memory fine

Tags: memory, swap

I have a 1GB VPS server. I setup 1GB of swap ram too a few weeks ago and quite often it's hitting 99% whilst the regular memory is usually 40% - 60%.

Most of my sites on the server run fine and fast. But the wordpress website I am developing is very slow. It's not public yet so even when I am on the backend updating a post for example it's slow, on the front end it's slow too etc.

I'm working on removing the plugins to try see what may improve if any but I think this is just building up overtime it seems, wasn't sudden.

Could maybe do with some suggestions on what to SSH and check into etc, what commands to run too. Here is a screenshot from a few minutes ago.

[image]

Comment: What is `swappiness` set to?

Answer (score 2):

Is the swapping contributing to the slowness, or is the wordpress instance always slow?

The OS will swap memory that's not being used much, so there might just be a lot of memory that's being allocated but sitting idle - for instance, this might be happening to the memory being used by your wordpress instance because it's not serving any hits while it's under development.

Comment: Right. It seems like his system is making a rational tradeoff. It doesn't have an awful lot of RAM, so it's moving rarely used stuff to swap to make more physical RAM available. The tradeoff is that when rarely used stuff is actually used, there's a performance hit. The benefit is that the most used stuff is faster.